# How to Animate 10 most recent gifs in a directory?

Tags: php, animation, directory, imagemagick, gif

Ok so im using a cron job to call this script every 15 mins

```
<?php

$time = microtime();

$handle_data = file_get_contents('http://www.bungie.net/Stats/Halo3/Nightmap.ashx');
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($handle_data);
$img->writeImage('nightmap/'.$time.'.gif');

?>
```

Now I want to get the 10 most recent gifs out of the "nightmap/" directory and animate them with a 3 second delay. Not really sure how to do this in imagemagick..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful for the animation stuff:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/

As for getting the 10 most recent images, I would put 'em in a database when you retrieve them, but if you don't want to... use `glob` to find all the files in the directory, use `usort` to sort them, and the comparison function you provide for `usort` will compare the `filemtime` of the files.